# Echo WordPress Post in Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, function

First, be gentle! I'm a javascript noob!

I have created a Codepen that replaces classes and applies transformations on element click via javascript. In the Codepen environment, it works perfectly. The problem comes when I try to transfer that same type of functionality to WordPress.

Here is the original javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#panel-1 a.get-big").click(function(){
    $("#panel-1").addClass("huge-panel");
    $("div:not(#panel-1)").removeClass("huge-panel");
    $("#panel-1 #the-top").addClass("move-in-top");
    $("#panel-1 #the-bottom").addClass("move-in-bottom");
    $("div:not(#panel-1 #the-top)").removeClass("move-in-top");
    $("div:not(#panel-1 #the-bottom)").removeClass("move-in-bottom");
  });
  $("#panel-2 a.get-big").click(function(){
    $("#panel-2").addClass("huge-panel");
    $("div:not(#panel-2)").removeClass("huge-panel");
    $("#panel-2 #the-top").addClass("move-in-top");
    $("#panel-2 #the-bottom").addClass("move-in-bottom");
    $("div:not(#panel-2 #the-top)").removeClass("move-in-top");
    $("div:not(#panel-2 #the-bottom)").removeClass("move-in-bottom");
  });
  $("#panel-3 a.get-big").click(function(){
    $("#panel-3").addClass("huge-panel");
    $("div:not(#panel-3)").removeClass("huge-panel");
    $("#panel-3 #the-top").addClass("move-in-top");
    $("#panel-3 #the-bottom").addClass("move-in-bottom");
    $("div:not(#panel-3 #the-top)").removeClass("move-in-top");
    $("div:not(#panel-3 #the-bottom)").removeClass("move-in-bottom");
  });
  $("#panel-4 a.get-big").click(function(){
    $("#panel-4").addClass("huge-panel");
    $("div:not(#panel-4)").removeClass("huge-panel");
    $("#panel-4 #the-top").addClass("move-in-top");
    $("#panel-4 #the-bottom").addClass("move-in-bottom");
    $("div:not(#panel-4 #the-top)").removeClass("move-in-top");
    $("div:not(#panel-4 #the-bottom)").removeClass("move-in-bottom");
  });
  $("#panel-5 a.get-big").click(function(){
    $("#panel-5").addClass("huge-panel");
    $("div:not(#panel-5)").removeClass("huge-panel");
    $("#panel-5 #the-top").addClass("move-in-top");
    $("#panel-5 #the-bottom").addClass("move-in-bottom");
    $("div:not(#panel-5 #the-top)").removeClass("move-in-top");
    $("div:not(#panel-5 #the-bottom)").removeClass("move-in-bottom");
  });
});
```

It's not elegant, but it is effective. [Here it is on Codepen](http://codepen.io/designoneweb/pen/OWYpZG).

Now for the question and the place where I get lost. I want to apply this to a WordPress custom loop. The only part of the javascript that would be necessary (I believe) is the first .click(function) routine that references #panel-1. Within the loop, I have used php to pull in the post_ID as the id of the div. I need to figure out a way to dynamically replace all instances of panel-1 within the javascript via the get_the_ID() call. From everything I've been able to gather here and elsewhere on the web, I assume this is going to use wp_localize_script somehow, but looking at that just confuses me.

Any help would be appreciated!